# jQuery plugin tutorial explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm following the [**JQuery Plugins/Authoring**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options) tutorial, and couldn't figure out what `arguments` on lines **16** and **18** mean. Am I missing something really fundamental?

```
(function( $ ){

var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { 
    // ... 
    },
    show : function( ) {
    // ...
};

$.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[ method ].
            apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

};

})( jQuery );
```

Thank you.

Comment: btw, is there anyway to show line numbers in code automatically? thx.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: to your comment, no. Show emphasis on a particular line using inline comments

Comment: (^_^ feeling like a noob) thx guys. @KevinB, I meant to the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arguments` is an **array-like** object that contains the parameters that were passed into the function, including parameters that you didn't supply a variable name for.

It is array-like, but not an array. It does not contain any of the array methods, such as slice, which is why you have to use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,...)` or `[].slice.call(arguments,...)` rather than just using `arguments.slice(...)`

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` is a JavaScript reserved keyword, which is an array containing all arguments passed to a function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/he95z461(v=vs.94).aspx